# How to handle the style of one element/index in a component rendered by an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to handle the style of an element in a component based on some parameters.

I have this code:

```
<View>
  {assignedPassengersData.map((info, index) => (
    <View
      key={info.id}
      opacity={info.id === passengerCardId ? 1 : 0.5}
    >
      <PassengersInfo
        id={info.id}
        buttonText={
          passengerCardId === info.id ? 'CONFIRM DROPOFF' : 'START NAVIGATING'
        }
        btnStyle={[
          passengerCardId === info.id
            ? { backgroundColor: '#263238' }
            : navigationStore.index
            ? { backgroundColor: Colors.pickupTabColor }
            : { backgroundColor: Colors.dropOffTabColor },
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  ))}
</View>
```

The prop I need to handle is `opacity`.

Here:

```
opacity={info.id === passengerCardId ? 1 : 0.5}
```

The way I have the code right now works only when that condition is met, so I can see the element I need with `opacity: 1`. So the rest of the elements always have `opacity: 0.5`. I need that when the app loads, everything should have `opacity: 1`. The when `info.id === passengerCardId` opacity should be set to `1` only in the element that mets the condition. Then the rest of the elements should have opacity set to `0.5`.

So, how can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would create an external function.

Something like:

```
getOpacity = infoId => {
   const {pessengerCardId} = this.props; ==> supposing your pessengerCardId comes from props;

   if(passengerCardId && infoId !== pessengerCardId) {
     return 0.5;
   }

   return 1;
}
```

Your code should looks like something like:

```
<View>
{assignedPassengersData.map((info, index) => (
   <View
     key={info.id}
     opacity={() => this.getOpacity(info.id)}
   >
     <PassengersInfo
      id={info.id}
      buttonText={
        passengerCardId === info.id ? 'CONFIRM DROPOFF' : 'START NAVIGATING'
      }
      btnStyle={[
        passengerCardId === info.id
          ? { backgroundColor: '#263238' }
          : navigationStore.index
          ? { backgroundColor: Colors.pickupTabColor }
          : { backgroundColor: Colors.dropOffTabColor },
      ]}
    />
  </View>
 ))}
</View>
```

Comment: Mmm but how do I invoke this function? Like just by calling it here `opacity={() => this.getOpacity(info.id)}` is not going to call the function.

Comment: In what moment u want to call? mouseover? onClick? Or right away after component rendered?

Comment: When the component render. I know I can do it on componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate, but then I will lose the param: `infoId`.

Comment: it should work since the render method will be called again as soon as the props changes, so the method getOpacity will be called again...

Comment: What I mean is how do I call the param `infoId`  if I call the function on any of the lifecycle methods?

Comment: Sorry, but I;m not getting your question... the info.id u r sending via parameter.

take a look at my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/61o59kv5jw

Comment: I got your example. But here you are calling this `opacity={() => this.getOpacity(info.id)}` and in the example this: `opacity={this.getOpacity(info.id)}` which is going to be call on every iteration. If I would have 300 items, just imagine that being call that many times.

Comment: That's what you want, the function does exactly what your code is doing (info.id === passengerCardId ? 1 : 0.5), but in an elegant way (outside). And also you probably have paging, you do not want to display 300 items at once or Am I wrong? Anyways, it was only a suggestion, that is not mandatory, but to do what you want to do

Comment: I just updated the example, using ur code. Take a look (same url).